# Convert array of objects into array of array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I currently have an array like so

```
["Name", "DOB", "Age", "Education"...]
```

but I want it to be an array of arrays so when I export to CSV then each question (Name, DOB etc) is its own column in the spreadsheet, i.e. I want it in the form like this:

```
[["Name"], ["DOB"], ["Age"], ["Education"], ...]
```

The code I have so far is like below:

```
const getQuestions = (data) => {
    const questionList = [];
    const dataItem = data.item;
    dataItem.forEach((element) => {
        const question = element.text;
        questionList.push(question);
    });
  return questionList;
};
```

Note: the element.text is the "Name", "DOB" question titles

Comment: The given array is not a array of objects

Comment: Hi @AnkitAgarwal yes, I want it to be an array of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let myArray = ["Name", "DOB", "Age", "Education"...];
 let arrayOfArray = myArray.map(item => [item]); // [['Name], ['DOB'], .. ];
```

Comment: If this was helpful, kindly upvote this answer and mark this as correct. :)

Comment: I am trying to export the data to a CSV using reactstrap's CSVLink component. Upon inspection, the data is in the format of `[["Name"], ["DOB"], .. ]` etc and not `[['Name'], ['DOB'], .. ]` - note the use of " and not ' - will this impact the export? It doesn't seem to be working in my excel spreadsheet as all the questions are in the first cell only

Comment: Seeing their documentation, it doesn't anywhere mention the use of `""` against `''` So I am going to say this is not going to be a problem.

Comment: Regarding on how to export, It is better if you post another question. Since this is not related to it. Also in the question it would be better if you shared your code as well. Try making replica in codesandbox.io for that question.